# How to Translate a Delegated Function to a IBAction Function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a delegate function that changes a UITableViewCell's section location on tap:

```
//On cell tap, expand
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        let data = firstDataSource[indexPath.row]

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        secondDataSource.append(data)
        firstDataSource.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: find(secondDataSource, data)!, inSection: 1)

        tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: newIndexPath)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let data = secondDataSource[indexPath.row]

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        firstDataSource.append(data)
        secondDataSource.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: find(firstDataSource, data)!, inSection: 0)

        tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: newIndexPath)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

I would like for this action to occur when I fire an IBAction from a button tap, but I'm not sure how I can access the indexPath argument as is given in the delegate function. Here is my current code for the IBAction button:

```
@IBAction func checkOffTask(sender: UIButton) {
    var checkedOff = false


    let indexOfCell = sender.tag
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox-checked"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: indexOfCell, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Any idea on how to get the delegate function to work for the IBAction function?

Comment: From whom is the action coming? An `IBAction` is just a graphically wired version of the target/action pattern, usually originating from a `UIControl` subclass in iOS.

Comment: The action is coming from a UIButton view.

Comment: So then which row are you expecting it to associate with? One that's currently selected?

Comment: Yeah, each row has its own button, so whenever that button is tapped, that specific row should change section locations.

Comment: Isn't your problem already solved with the `NSIndexPath(forItem: indexOfCell, inSection: 1)`?

Comment: Somewhat, `let indexOfCell = sender.tag` returns 0 for me no matter which cell I tap, so I'm guessing that's not a reliable way to get the index number of a cell.

Comment: No, you have to supply the `tag` first — the system isn't filling it in. So the solution you appear to have half of is to store the index path within the tag when populating the cell, then read it back later. Is there possibly some omission or mistake (like an `if` that goes the wrong way) in your code that puts contents into the cell?

Comment: Alright, so I'm successfully storing the `index.row` of each cell within the button tags, but since I can only store an int within the tag, I can't store the cells' `index.section`, which I need in order to create an `indexPath` object and decide which section to send the cell to on tap. `var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: indexOfCell, inSection: int)` returns an error since I can't give it the button's section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so your action is coming from a button, that button is within a table view cell, the question is: what's the indexPath of that table view cell.

The easiest way is:

1. get the location of the button within the table view;
2. ask for the index path at that position.

E.g.

```
@IBAction func checkOffTask(sender: UIButton!) {
    let originInTableView = self.tableView.convertPoint(CGPointZero, fromView: sender)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(originInTableView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a workaround I have used before.
Doesn't look pretty but does the job:

```
UIButton *likeButton = (UIButton *)sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)likeButton.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Just find the correct superview for the button which is of UICollectionView Class type.

P.S. - My Swift is not the best. Hoping you can convert this.

Comment: Nice man, I didn't know you could select superviews like that, that's pretty sweet. I was able to translate it to Swift and it works perfectly, thanks a ton!

Comment: That'll likely break in future versions of iOS. The cell's `contentView` has no guaranteed nesting within its parent. Your code will fail if it ever stops being a direct child.