# Objective-C: TableView Sections and indexPaths Working With Arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been struggling with the logic on this problem for a couple of hours, hopefully someone can help me out.

My app has an array of contacts which are in my address book and ALSO using the app (self.societyContacts).

I break that array and place it into sections in my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.itsToDoChecked = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<self.societyContacts.count; i++) {
        [self.itsToDoChecked insertObject:@"FALSE" atIndex:i];
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];

    [self.societyContacts sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    BOOL found;

    // Loop through the books and create our keys
    for (NSDictionary *contact in self.societyContacts)
    {
        NSString *c = [[contact objectForKey:@"firstName"] substringToIndex:1];

        found = NO;

        for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
        {
            if ([str isEqualToString:c])
            {
                found = YES;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
    }

    for (NSDictionary *contact in self.societyContacts)
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:[[contact objectForKey:@"firstName"] substringToIndex:1]] addObject:contact];
    }

    [self.contactsTable reloadData];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Here are all of the TableView delegate methods I am using to display the data:

```
#pragma mark UITableView

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.sections allKeys] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}
```

Now, here is the problem. Everything works great up until this point.

Each contact cell has a button which acts as a checkbox, so I can tell which ones have been picked by the user.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath I use the following code to set up the cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SocietyContactCell";

    SocietyContactCell *cell = (SocietyContactCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SocietyContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *contact = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *fName = [contact objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    NSString *lName = [contact objectForKey:@"lastName"];

    if (fName == nil && lName == nil) {

        NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [contact valueForKey:@"phoneNumbers"]];
        cell.nameLabel.text = label;

    } else if (fName == nil) {

        NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [contact valueForKey:@"lastName"]];

        cell.nameLabel.text = label;

    } else if (lName == nil) {

        NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [contact valueForKey:@"firstName"]];

        cell.nameLabel.text = label;

    } else {

        NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [contact valueForKey:@"firstName"], [contact valueForKey:@"lastName"]];

        cell.nameLabel.text = label;

    }


    BOOL checked =  [[self.itsToDoChecked objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedContact.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedContact.png"];

    [cell.checkButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;

}
```

And now the button action. I'm not sure how to get the correct index path row from the cell to pass to the button action so I can deal with it properly. Right now, the button keeps changing as the user scrolls up and down.

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int row = button.tag;

    NSLog(@"row: %i", row);
    NSLog(@"row: %i", row);    

    BOOL checked = [[self.itsToDoChecked objectAtIndex:row] boolValue];
    [self.itsToDoChecked removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    [self.itsToDoChecked insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:row];

    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedContact.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedContact.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

If anyone has some advice on how to get the correct index path row for the button tag, so I can make sure the check buttons are operating correctly and I have access to the correct contact for other programming needs, that would be great.

Comment: is the tableView shows data Correctly as you expected?

Comment: it shows the data correctly, and I can check/uncheck the button. But when I scroll, the buttons show incorrectly checked/uncheked when the cells are reused because of the issue with the button tag being incorrect (not sure how to do it using sections)

Comment: You need to review self.itsToDoChecked since  you don,t have it based on sections as contacts, and then button will works as expected.   right now once you changed button status on a row all buttons on other sections with same row index  get changed too.

Comment: [See the accepted answer for this question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700208/how-to-translate-a-delegated-function-to-a-ibaction-function/32702680#32702680

Answer (score 0):

You need to review self.itsToDoChecked since you don't have it based on sections as contacts, and then button will not works as expected. right now once you changed button status on a row all buttons on other sections with same row index get changed too. 
To resolve the problem you can use the same pattern you used to save contacts for section to save toDoChecked for section.
...

```
self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.itsToDoCheckedInSections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

....

```
for (NSDictionary *contact in self.societyContacts){

 [[self.sections objectForKey:[[contact objectForKey:@"firstName"] substringToIndex:1]] addObject:contact];

 [[self.itsToDoCheckedInSections objectForKey:[[contact objectForKey:@"firstName"] substringToIndex:1]] addObject:@"FALSE"];
}
```

....

In cellForRow

```
NSDictionary *contact = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

BOOL *checked = [[[self.itsToDoCheckedInSections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
```

in buttonPress

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int row = button.tag;

//be sure of your view hierarchy perhaps you need more superview to get SocietyContactCell then the needed section
    SocietyContactCell *cell = (SocietyContactCell *)[button superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"row: %i", row);
    NSLog(@"row: %i", row); 

    BOOL *checked = [[[self.itsToDoCheckedInSections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

...

    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedContact.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedContact.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```